# overlay of shapefile on iOS apple maps (mapkit)

Tags: ios, pdf, svg, dictionary, png

We have a mapping application currently in the app store (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/atlanta-fire/id825146524?ls=1&mt=8) and now we would like to add one or two overlays (the city limits, county limits, etc).

I have this GIS data available as a shape file and can also export as a pdf, png, svg, mbtiles and as a MapNik XML.

I do not want to override the native apple map (such as with Open Streets or MapBox), but just need to incorporate the shape file info.

Suggested strategies?

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on something similar.  There is a Shapefile C Library that I found
[here](http://shapelib.maptools.org/):

Also there is a sample project that incorporates this into Mapkit [here](https://github.com/altyus/Mapkit_ShapeFile):

Comment: I had seen the first link but not the second. I'll post any updates. Thanks!